# Persistently save chrome devtools settings

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

**My Goal**: Persistently save settings of google-chrome-devtools settings for console. Specifically the "User messages only" option.

**Problem**: If I check that option, close and open the devtools again, the options is unchecked again. So the changes I make are not persisted.

**Question**: Is that behavior normal?

Thanks for your time (Y) :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug.

Star this issue to give it more attention: https://crbug.com/734088

Update: It's not a bug per se, the team intended for it to work like this. But I think it makes more sense for the setting to persist.